# How to run a process as an administrator from Win32 \C++

Tags: winapi

I have a console application written in c#, which downloads a file to program files. So of course it needs to run as admin. This program gets called from a Win32 C++ application which almost certainly is not running as administrator
What are my options. How can I get this to work on UAC and non UAC enabled boxes ( I don't know if there needs to be separate solution in each case )
Oh and the console app is in .NET 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a machine with UAC you need to include a [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) resource to specify that you want the process to run as administrator.

On a machine without UAC you will simply have to instruct your users that they need to run it as a user in the administrators group. Almost all users of XP (the version that you will most commonly encounter without UAC) are in the administrators group so you won't encounter many problems.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it, but this can probably be done using the

[CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Function.

Comment: In order to call this, you need a user token with rights to the Program Files folder. Where are you going to get such a token?

Comment: You can create the token using the LogonUser Function(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as referenced in the documentation

Comment: Yes you can create such a token. But you need to know the username and password!!

Comment: You don't run servers with CreateProcessAsUser and an admin password being sent in plaintext!

Comment: Your reality perhaps. Not my reality.