# Ask for elevated permission using

Tags: c, winapi, uac

How can I ask for elevated permissions.

Like this:

```
// Prompt UAC, 
    if (UACprompt == Yes)
    {
        system("C:\\Users\\Gadr\\Desktop\\hi.exe");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please run as admin");
    }
```

Comment: Why? Why do you need elevated privileges? What actual problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261427/how-to-run-a-process-as-an-administrator-from-win32-c. The subjct is vast.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Because the hi.exe file needs elevated pri... to execute properly

Comment: I found a solution https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320748/Elevating-During-Runtime

Comment: Add the appropriate manifest to your executable

Comment: @Godless if `hi.exe` requires elevated permissions to run properly, then it is `hi.exe`'s responsibility to request elevation for itself, that is not the caller's responsibility to do. `hi.exe` needs a UAC manifest that specifies an appropriate `requestedExecutionLevel` for its needs, such as `requireAdministrator`